# How does ember fetch perform ajax query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I'm using ember-fetch and from it's [source code](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-fetch) I cannot figure out where it made the call XHR call.

In another word, where does it call `window.XMLHttpRequest`?

Coming from a jQuery background, I'm also trying to figure out where can we specify option such as `processData = false` as [seen in here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings), but this time I want it in `ember-fetch`-way.

Comment: _"where does it call window.XMLHttpRequest"_ it doesn't. As it says at the top of the README, it's a _"HTML5 [fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) polyfill from [github](https://github.com/github/fetch) wrapped and bundled for ember-cli users."_. See also [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Comment: to add, ember-fetch isn't needed if all your `targets` support `fetch` already (chrome, firefox, etc)

Comment: I'm not the OP but your answers made me pretty confused. If `ember-fetch` is a polyfill for `fetch`, how the heck can it uses `fetch` internally?

Comment: @CristianTraìna, `ember-fetch` is a wrapper for a polyfil, https://github.com/github/fetch. That is the the tool that actually calls `XmlHttpRequest`, as you can see from the source code: https://github.com/github/fetch/search?q=XmlHttpRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In another word, where does it call `window.XMLHttpRequest`?

Short answer is: it doesn’t. [Its repo](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-fetch) says *“HTML5 fetch polyfill from github wrapped and bundled for ember-cli users”*, so it does what is says on the tin, it uses the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead.

> (…) I'm also trying to figure out where can we specify option such as `processData = false`

Right, if I understand this correctly, `fetch` by default does not process the data it gets, that’s why you see so many examples with something like `response.json()` (like on the [repo you linked](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-fetch#usage)).